# How to find data in mongodb using TMongoWire

Tags: delphi, mongodb

I need find a data object in mongo using field value "codigo". I am using TMongoWire.

My code

Insert values:

```
     FMongoWire.Insert(
        'johni.alunos', BSON( [
          'id', mongoObjectId,
          'codigo', '1',
          'nome', 'Johni Douglas Marangon'
        ] ) );
```

This code I am using find data, this code not data result.

```
    var
      Document: IBSONDocument;
    begin
      Document:= FMongoWire.Get( 'johni.alunos', BSON['codigo', '1'] );
```

This code too not result data

```
    var
      WireQuery: TMongoWireQuery;
      Document: IBSONDocument;]
    begin
      Document: BSON;

      WireQuery:= TMongoWireQuery.Create( FMongoWire );
      try
        WireQuery.Query( 'johni.alunos' , BSON( [ 'codigo', '1' ] ) );

        WireQuery.Next( Document );

        Result:= VarToStr( Document[ 'nome' ] );

      finally
        FreeAndNil( WireQuery );

      end;
    end;
```

If I use ObjectID value it works.

Anyone know how I can do a search using the fields values TMongoWire, which are not the ObjectId?

Thanks

Comment: please clarify your question

Comment: Can you please clarify how you use ObjectID to make it work? And why this working way won't work for what you want?

Comment: As an alternative to this driver, you may take a look at [our Open Source *SynMongoDB* library](http://blog.synopse.info/post/2014/05/07/MongoDB-database-access), just released. Thanks to our `TDocVariant` custom variant type, work with documents is pretty straightforward. And it has some nice features like BULK insert or delete, and 100% JSON support for the queries (with extended *MongoDB* syntax).

Answer (score 0):

weird, I did a look at a small test program a colleague made, and it seems identical.
However with a small change:

```
  d := BSON(['codigo','1']);
  q := TMongoWireQuery.Create(FMongoWire);
  try
    q.Query('johni.alunos',d);
    if q.Next(d) then
    begin
      //found!
    end;
  finally
    q.Free;
  end;
```

Second, maybe you can try "umongo" and look at the data in the collection?
http://www.edgytech.com/umongo

Then you can do a "connect" to your db and a "find" (right click) on your collection with the following query:

```
{ codigo: 1 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution the problem https://github.com/stijnsanders/TMongoWire/issues/14

Thanks

Comment: Oh you've added it here. (With a link?!) The actual situation also actually isn't derivable from the question here. StackOverflow moderators won't like this.